# Adding n vectors in a for loop

Tags: r, distribution, dice

I can do this the following way.

```
throws = 10000

dieone = function(n) sample(1:6, n, rep = T)
dietwo = function(n) sample(1:6, n, rep = T)
diethree = function(n) sample(1:6, n, rep = T)
diefour = function(n) sample(1:6, n, rep = T)

die1 <- dieone(throws)
die2 <- dietwo(throws)
die3 <- diethree(throws)
die4 <- diefour(throws)

dice <- die1 + die2 + die3 + die4
h <- hist(dice)
```

I would like to use a `for` loop or something that can do as many dice I want.

Comment: In general, if the body of two (or more) functions is identical, you only need one.

Comment: Why do you have to create `dieone` , `dietwo`, `diethree` and `diefour` as separate fucntion? You can use any one function out of those 4  to create `die1`, `die2`, `die3` and `die4` .

Comment: `rep=TRUE` is secure